# Windows 7 is stuck in boot loop

Tags: windows-7, boot

Windows 7 failed to boot.

When I start normally, it returns me to that screen after a restart. When I start Diagnostics, it shows a loading screen, but it does not load.

The hardware used is a Sony (r) Vaio computer (model PCG-71C11M). The battery is damaged, and the hard drive is in need of repair, due to some unindexed files.

Comment: Old hard drives usually cannot be usefully repaired. Get a new drive and install Windows 7 on the new drive.

Comment: @John `chkdsk` complained about the journal... this happens too often...

Comment: @Oliver If chkdsk is finding errors often, that is a **clear** sign of an upcoming hardware failure. Also Windows 7 is EOL for more than a year now and not receiving any updates.